# Uniqueness of $\infty$-adjoints

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, adjoint-functors

Adjoints in a 2-category are essentially unique, in the following strong sense.  If $\mathbf{2}$ denotes the "walking arrow" category $(\cdot \to \cdot)$, then there is a 2-category $\mathrm{Adj}_1$ with two objects, and a map $\mathbf{2}\to \mathrm{Adj}_1$, such that for any 2-category $K$ the precomposition functor $\mathrm{Cat}(\mathrm{Adj}_1,K) \to \mathrm{Cat}(\mathbf{2},K)$ is fully faithful and its image consists of the 1-morphisms in $K$ with right adjoints.

Is an analogous fact true for adjoints in an $(\infty,2)$-category?  If so, what is the $(\infty,2)$-category $\mathrm{Adj}_{\infty}$?  A natural conjecture would be that $\mathrm{Adj}_{\infty} = \mathrm{Adj}_1$; I'm not quite sure whether to hope for that.

(I'm assuming that an "adjoint" in an $(\infty,2)$-category $K$ means a morphism whose image in the homotopy 2-category of $K$ has an adjoint in the usual sense.  So in a sense, this question is about "coherentification" of adjoints.)

Comment: Would the Riehl-Verity walking adjunction give a decent hint as to how to proceed?

Comment: At least in the $(\infty,2)$-category of $(\infty,1)$-categories a left adjoint is not simply a functor which is a left adjoint in the homotopy category. Rather, it has to satisfy the opportune universal property mirroring the 1-categorical notion. I think that, with your notation but the "correct" definition, $\textrm{Adj}_\infty=\textrm{Adj}_1$.

Comment: @DavidRoberts indeed.  I should have remembered that.

Comment: Mike said "homotopy 2-category", not "homotopy 1-category", @DenisNardin. With the 2 the statement is correct.

Comment: Well, it doesn't even make sense to talk about "adjoints" in a 1-category.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, and $\mathrm{Adj}_\infty = \mathrm{Adj}_1$.  This is Theorem 4.4.18 of [Riehl-Verity](http://www.math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/adjunctions.pdf).  Thanks David, I should have remembered that.

Comment: I thought perhaps you knew this, and it was obviously not enough! :-) Glad to help.

Comment: Since this question got bumped up, maybe it's worth pointing out that Lurie also proves a closely related statement as Theorem 3.2.10 in DAG-II (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702299) - and even uses it in his first proof of the Barr-Beck theorem, just like Riehl-Verity do. Later, in Higher Algebra, Lurie apparently found a different way to show that the monad associated to an adjunction is an algebra object (by characterizing it via a universal property as an algebra), and so this theorem didn't survive to the now more-standard text.