Reduction of the $0$-handle data in Lurie's classification of TFT
A vital part of Jacob Lurie's classification of fully extended topological
field theories [1], very roughly, says that any representation of the
n-Cobordism category $Z: {\rm Cob}_{{n}} \to C$ depends only on its value on the point
$Z(\ast) \in C_{0}$ (cf Theorem 2.4.6 of [1]).
A priori, this is surprising because ${\rm Cob}_{n}$ is a huge category, containing at
least every smooth manifold of dimension $n$. The key to reduce the data of
$Z$ down to $Z(\ast)$ lies in the fact that every smooth manifold can be broken
into handle decompositions. Moreover, in any given dimension $d \leq n$ and any
$0 \leq k \leq (d-1)$, a $k$-handle attachment $u$ and a $(k+1)$-handle attachment
$v$ forms a pair of unit/counit that witnesses an adjunction in dimension
$(d-1)$. And since the counit is determined up to isomorphism by the unit (cf
Lemma 2.3.8 of [1]), in dimension $d$, the data of $Z$ are reduced to the
datum $Z(B^{d}: \phi^{d-1} \to S^{d-1})$, i.e. the value in $C$ assigned to the
$d$-dimensional $0$-handle attachment, where $\phi^{d-1}$ denotes the empty manifold
of dimension $(d-1)$. This reduction is stated formally in the "Cobordism
Hypothesis, Inductive Formulation" (cf Theorem 3.1.8 of [1]).
To sum up, so far, I have reduced $Z$ to the collection
$$Z(\ast), Z(B^{1}: \phi^{0} \to S^{0}), \ldots, Z(B^{n}: \phi^{n-1} \to S^{n-1}).$$
Therefore, to conclude the main theorem Theorem 2.4.6 from Theorem 3.1.8, one
needs to argue that the aforementioned $Z(B^{d})$ are uniquely determined (up to
isomorphism) once $Z(\ast)$ is given. This is what's claimed to be done in the
long sketch/argument in page 55 and 56 of [1]. There, the author transforms the
data in several steps. The part that confuses me is step (8), where the
author got rid of $\eta$ from the data $(c_{0})$ to the data $(c_{1})$, where $$\eta: Z(\phi^{n-1}) = {\rm id}_1 \to (g \circ f) = Z(S^{n-1}).$$
Indeed, we have Lemma 2.3.8 that guarantees the uniqueness of the counit once
the unit is given. But this alone does not justify that $\eta$ is determined from the lower dimensional data $f, g$. The problem would go away if the witnessing unit/counit pair is unique, i.e. the following statement:
Statement (Too good to be true?) . If $f, g$ are adjoint in a strict $2$-category witnessed by two pairs of unit/counit $(u,v), (u', v')$, then $u = u'$ and $v = v'$.
However, I can't find any internal or external reference for this, and in fact I think this is not true in general, yet throughout [1] the author keeps on
mentioning "the unit" of a adjoint pair.
TLDR
Question. How to make a more complete justification of the reduction $(c_{0}) \rightsquigarrow (c_{1})$?
If this is false, then the classification problem becomes messier.
Reference
[1] J. Lurie - On the Classification of Topological Field Theories

The correct $2$-categorical statement is the following: if $f$ is a $1$-morphism that admits a right adjoint, then the space (i.e. $2$-groupoid) of triples $(g,u,c)$ exhibiting $g$ as a right adjoint to $f$ is contractible.

It's also true that given $(f,g,u)$ then $c$ is unique, as you mentioned, so the space of triples $(g,u,c)$ mentioned in the previous comment is isomorphic to the space of pairs $(g,u)$ such that there exists a $c$ (which we know is then unique) such that $(f,g,c,u)$ is an adjunction.

So the space of pairs $(g,u)$ above is contractible. The move you describe simply discards $(g,u)$.

@ManuelAraújo I would love to have a reference or a complete proof for this! In particular, in for a strict category, the space of the triples $(g,u,c)$ should be a single point, right? I couldn't prove this even for the most classical case, i.e. when $f$ is a functor between two categories.

The space of triples won't be a single point, as there could be many different right adjoints. But it will be contractible. I wrote a proof of this in section 3 here: https://compositionality.episciences.org/13516/pdf (although it was of course known before).

@ManuelAraújo I appreciate for your explanation for strict $2$-category in your paper! Now I'm worried.. I thought the problem would go away once we prove the essential uniqueness for strict $2$-cats. However, you had to prove it for strict $3$-cats (in the same paper), and Riehl-Veriy had to prove it for $qCat_\infty$ (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/231867/uniqueness-of-infty-adjoints). Who had prove this for general $(\infty,n)$-cats, or at least for the cobordism categories $Cob_n$? Any reference? Or is it something that is accepted by folklore without a careful proof?

I think Lurie's argument always uses adjoints in a homotopy $2$-category, so only the $2$-categorical facts about adjunctions are necessary in the proof, but I admit I don't remember it in detail. It's also good to keep in mind that this is a proof sketch.
